# Hide/Show drop menu based on other drop menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Recently I have been tasked with learning MVC for work. I have run into a scenario where I need to show a drop menu based on another drop menu selection. My cshtml is here:

```html
@using(Html.BeginForm("Make","Order")) {
    <fieldset>
        <h4>Selection1</h4>
        <select id="MAIN" name="main">
            <option value="X">X</option>
            <option value="Y">Y</option>
            <option value="Z">Z</option>
        </select>
        <select id="showForY" name="yOPT" hidden>
            <option value="Y-2">Y-2</option>
            <option value="Y-3">Y-3</option>
        </select>
        <select id="showForZ" name="zOPT" hidden>
            <option value="Z-2">Z-2</option>
            <option value="Z-3">Z-3</option>
        </select>
        <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        <button id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">Reset Form</button>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I want to be able to have the `showForY` to show only when value Y is selected in the main select field. How would I do this? I know it is possible to do it with either JavaScript or jQuery, but have never work with them.

Comment: This is definitely something you can use jQuery for. jQuery is an incredibly useful library. I would recommend going through a couple of tutorials. This might be a good starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
#showForY {
   display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#MAIN').on('change', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == 'Y') {
       $('#showForY').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
       $('#showForY').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: thought it had to do with jQuery. I will add this to my project when I get to my computer where everything is stored!